# How to assign column values on modified rows R?

Tags: r, time, data.table

I'm looking to create a column from another column row taking into account that rows position. Below is my sample data:

```
library(data.table)


latemail <- function(N, st="2012/01/01", et="2012/01/07") {
  st <- as.POSIXct(as.Date(st))
  et <- as.POSIXct(as.Date(et))
  dt <- as.numeric(difftime(et,st,unit="sec"))
  ev <- sort(runif(N, 0, dt))
  rt <- st + ev

}

#create our data frame
set.seed(42)
dt = latemail(100000)
work = setDT(as.data.frame(dt))
work$worker = stringi::stri_rand_strings(1000, 5)   
work$dt = as.POSIXct(as.character(work$dt), tz = "GMT")

#order
work = work[order(work$worker, work$dt),]

#apply difftime
options(scipen=999)
work[, time_diff:= c(NA, diff(dt)), by = worker] #hours
work$time_diff = as.numeric(work$time_diff)
```

Now what I'm looking for is the following:

```
                    dt worker time_diff       dt2
 1: 2011-12-31 19:32:12  04nFT        NA       2011-12-31 21:00:10
 2: 2011-12-31 21:00:10  04nFT  1.466111        2011-12-31 22:22:04
 3: 2011-12-31 22:22:04  04nFT  1.365000       2011-12-31 23:47:04
 4: 2011-12-31 23:47:04  04nFT  1.416667       2012-01-01 01:16:04
 5: 2012-01-01 01:16:04  04nFT  1.483333        the next time
```

Essentially for each worker in each row, im moving the dt value from the row after it. Below is where I'm at. In this way, the last record of each row for dt will have an NA for dt2. Am I on the right track, not sure if I need to loop through?

```
work[, dt2:= c(NA, #something here
), by = worker]
```

Comment: The `dt` value from the row after it is `shift(dt, type="lead")` or `c(NA, dt[-1])`, I think. Fyi, assignment with `$name <-` is discouraged with data.table. Have a look at the vignettes if you haven't already: http://r-datatable.com/Getting-started

Comment: Also, use `setorder` not `work <- work[order(...)]`. See `?setorder` for details.